# Redaction in Tableau

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

I am currently in the process of building some Tableau workbooks where we will need to redact visualizations or text tables if the results fall below a certain threshold (e.g. only ten data points are returned after filters are applied). Does anyone know how to create calculated fields or know of other methods to redact in Tableau?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a threshold filter that compares the number of filtered responses to a threshold value set in a parameter.

First, create a parameter with integer data type and set it to the desired threshold. In this example, I called it `Count Threshold`.

Then create a calculated field for the filter with an equation like the following:

```
{FIXED: COUNTD([Respondent ID]) >= [Count Threshold]}
```

(I did this for survey results where we needed to hide results if the filtered number of respondents was fewer than 10.)

For the threshold filter to be applied after your other filters, choose "Add to Context" for your other filters.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but it got me close enough to figure out exactly what I needed to do. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution on the [Tableau community forum/knowledgebase about redaction](https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000C5iBK/partially-redacting-information-via-calculation) that might work for other implementations.

The basic idea is to create two different calculated fields, one which displays a integer value and the other that displays a string value. That way, when both are concatenated in the display you get the desired output without breaking any of the calculated field rules.

So create a calculated field that has a formula like:

```
IF sum([Datafield_to_Redact]) < 10 THEN "*" ELSE str(sum([Datafield_to_Redact])) END
```

And another that has a calculated field that has a formula like:

```
IF sum([Datafield_to_Redact]) < 10 THEN null ELSE sum([Datafield_to_Redact]) END
```

In the post the attached workbook and screenshot show how the two values are concatenated in the Text mark.

[Workbook screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQhdO.png)